# Windows Forms - Add Items to Combo Box Through Code

Tags: winforms, combobox

I am trying to dynamically add items to a Combobox in Windows Forms when pushing a button. I have tried several different ways and I am getting some odd behaviour. In one case I could see an item in the combobox but when I ran ComboBox.Items.Count it gave me 0 even though there was an item in the box. I tried using combobox.Refresh() to see if maybe there was some kind of sync issue but that didn't do anything either.

I am using the following code but it doesn't display anything in the box. ComboBox1.Items.Count gives me 10.

```
List<string> items = new List<string>();            
            for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
            {
                items.Add("item " + i.ToString());
            }
            ComboBox1.DataSource = items;
```

I am using Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: Do you have a ComboBox named `TestBox1`? If it's actually a ComboBox, it's just `[Some ComboBox].DataSource = items;`. No need for an array or casting to object. -- Or `[Some ComboBox].Items.AddRange(items);` -- Or `[Some ComboBox].Items.Add($"Item {i}");` in the loop, etc. -- Make sure you're using the *right* Control.

Comment: Ok I have updated my code with your suggestion. It's not displaying the items for some reason.

Comment: Are sure that this `ComboBox1` is the Control you see on screen? Did you check whether the Control's ForeColor is, for some reason, the same as the BackColor? -- From the description, it looks like you have at least two ComboBox Controls, maybe overlapping each other (or one is offs-screen or *under* another Control). -- Verify in the PropertyGrid how many Controls you have there.

Comment: No nothing is overlapping it. I also renamed it with a very unique name and still have the same problem.

Comment: Testing this in LinqPad (only +declaration and `ComboBox1.Dump();` at the end) works fine. Any problem does not seem to be in this part of the code.

Comment: I tested this in a new project and it worked. So now I am really confused. Any idea what would make it stop working?

Comment: Ok I have isolated the problem to the following lines of code which are called before my code above.
```NewUserPanel.Dispose();
InitializeComponent();```

The code is to reset a form back to blank after creating a new user.

Comment: Ok it seems to be this line of code causing the problem:
```InitializeComponent();```

Comment: `InitializeComponent()` is called only once, in the Constructor of a Form. If, for some reason, it's being called somewhere else, then it has to be removed. There's no reason to call it twice.

Comment: I was using it to reset a form to its blank/default state. Someone suggested it on another question.